# Can you save your app progress between different apple devices?

Tags: music, apple-id, data-transfer

I'm changing iPads soon for school from a old ipad to a new ipad air. I was wondering if I used the same Apple ID, could have save the progress from the games or apps I have in the old ipad and keep them in the new one. I know it saves the game so that you don't have to pay for it again just in care it isn't free. But, let's say I wanna save my Flappy Bird high score. If I get the app on my new ipad air, is there a way I could open the app up without having to start from 0 again. Also, documents in the notability app, is their an easier way to transport them to the new ipad. And music as well? Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends = if the games use Game Centre or their own net based server then yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can transfer all data from your old iPad to your new one with a backup, either with iCloud or iTunes on your computer. There is probably not enough space to backup to iCloud, but if you back up to a computer with iTunes, and then plug your iPad Air into that computer, it will ask if you want to set it up from the backup of your old iPad.